# nav bar menu item, removed and now a blank space

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm assisting someone on migrating a website and they wanted to remove a link from their nav bar. I inspected the element, found it in the css file and removed it with display:none but now it's just gone and everything else is static so there's a big blank space. Here's a picture:

[image]

I'm not a master at CSS, but is there a quick fix for this, or should I inspect each element and just move it over to the left?

UPDATE:

Before picture - with the retailer location link active

[image]

URL - Velvetfinishes.com

UPDATE 2:

Here is the css code currently after taking visbility:hidden out of clearfix:

```
.clearfix:after /* force a container to fit around floated items */
{
content: "\0020";
/*visibility: hidden;*/
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: a piece of code or link to website will help to investigate

Comment: Can you post a before picture? I'm unsure of what is happening here.

Comment: are you sure you didn't use `display: hidden`?  This would be typical for this behaviour - `display: none` shouldn't leave any space

Comment: Sorry, just edited. @techLove I added the URl.

Comment: @Oliwol there is now a before pic with the link active

Comment: @Johannes yes, positive. That's why I thought it was weird

Comment: Try using: visibility: hidden;

Comment: Instead of display:none?

Comment: @Oliwol no - exacty the opposite!

Comment: Yeah, I think that would just do what is already happening. Display:none should remove it completely, but it's not doing that. Visibility:hidden doesn't make any difference here anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clearfix class on this element which adds a pseudo element that has `visibility: hidden` which leaves blank space, which is the problem. You should remove the `clearfix` class from that `div`

ADDITION:

I just realized that all menu DIVs have position settings, for example the next one (`#u2940`)  has `left: 504px`. If you change that to 362px, it moves to the left and fills the gap. And similarly for the other subsequent ones. You'll have to find the values by trying them in the inspector.

That's some rather strange CSS, I wonder why they did it like this...

Comment: From the whole navigation div? What would be the best way to remove that class?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just trying to replicate what I'm doing in the inspector

Comment: I'm updating code with my css, i just removed the visibility attribute from the clearfix class in one of my css files but same issue

Comment: no, only remove the `.clearfix` class itself from the `div` tag that has ID `u2968`

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry I'm not able to find clearfix attached to it in any of the CSS. I do see what you mean in the inspector though

Comment: hmm, I didn't mean the CSS, I meant the HTML, but I am afraid you can't change the HTML? Otherwise you would have simply deleted that tag... - wrong thinking from my side - I'll think a bit more about it...

Comment: please note the addition to my answer